# Statistical summary data with time series

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

I think I'm missing something with my understanding of group by in pandas. I've got my Dataframe indexed on 'Date' and the frame has a column called 'Year' where 2014-10-10 is 2014, etc.

The point is I want to correlate Year 1 data to Year 2 data, and so on. What am I supposed to do with a list of index values?

My input is:

```
Date    Adj Close   Year
2013-Dec-31 0.16    2013
2013-Dec-30 0.13    2013
2013-Dec-27 0.11    2013
2012-Dec-31 0.1     2012
2012-Dec-28 0.1     2012
2012-Dec-27 0.1     2012
2012-Dec-26 0.1     2012
```

and to do the correlation they must be side by side frames?

```
Date    Adj Close   Year    Date    Adj Close   Year
2012-Dec-31 0.1     2012    2013-Dec-31 0.16    2013
2012-Dec-28 0.1     2012    2013-Dec-30 0.13    2013
2012-Dec-27 0.1     2012    2013-Dec-27 0.11    2013
```

Do I have to make a new dataframe for each year group and merge them?

Comment: I dont understand what you're achieving to do. ``to correlate Year 1 data to Year 2 data'' ? Also, please provide in more detail what you are actually running - the code that creates your first output.

Comment: Really it's just the second half of my post that is the point, I've just been trying several ways and can't figure it out. I got all the years into a list of frames but when I do the join no data gets added of course because while the day and month may line up the year does not.

Answer (score 0):

There is no merge to be done. All your data is date-specific, just "stack" the data behind each other, and then make sure you group by month,day to get the yearly correlation (for the same day)

Just make sure that your index is a proper time series, and then pandas will do all the magic for you. That is, have a look at [this](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html)and [this](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/computation.html) in the manual. Any function that uses the index to weight against / compute distances, will automatically do this correctly for you if your index is a time series.

Here, I will plot the autocorrelation for you, again from the [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/visualization.html#visualization-autocorrelation)

```
df = pd.read_clipboard()
df.index = pd.DatetimeIndex(df.Date)
from pandas.tools.plotting import autocorrelation_plot
autocorrelation_plot(df['Adj')
```

and the output is

[image: Output]

If you want to apply additional filtering, with this index, you can even select a specific year using `df['2013']`.

Comment: Thank you for this, but I don't fully understand what I'm looking at. 
I've made this with the entire data set:  http://s4.postimg.org/9572dbjp9/output.png
and the original data is:
 http://s28.postimg.org/ywbow9y31/output2.png
I know 2014 has an R of ~.66 but don't see how to see that from the autocorrelation graph?

Comment: Perhaps you need to start a new question, and *clearly* ask what your data looks like, and what your expected outcome is. It is very difficult for me to guess what you want to do given what you have written here, and given that no one else has given your question a shot, I'm not the only one.